# Mysql : Get diagnonstic condition returns null

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have written following mysql stored procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`clocery`@`%` PROCEDURE `ADMIN_ADD_NEW_USER`(IN `IN_FIRST_NAME` varchar(50),IN `IN_LAST_NAME` varchar(50),IN `IN_USER_NAME` varchar(50), IN `IN_EMAIL` varchar(50),IN `IN_PASSWORD` varchar(80),IN `IN_ROLE` varchar(20),IN `IN_CREATED_BY` INT,OUT `OUT_STATUS` char(1),OUT `OUT_MESSAGE` varchar(200))
BEGIN
    DECLARE logged_in_user_role_id INT;
    DECLARE to_be_created_user_role_id INT;
    DECLARE user_who_created_logged_in_user INT;
    DECLARE matching_row_count_user_name INT;
    DECLARE matching_row_count_user_e_mail INT;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;

            GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;

            CALL UTIL_LOG_ERROR( 'ADMIN_ADD_NEW_USER', @sqlState, @errno, @text);

            SELECT 'N', UTIL_GET_ERROR_MESSAGE( 'some-error' )
                INTO OUT_STATUS, OUT_MESSAGE;

    END;

    /**
        * If passed user_id is NULL.
        */
    IF IN_CREATED_BY = NULL THEN
        SELECT 'N', UTIL_GET_ERROR_MESSAGE( 'some-error' ) 
                INTO OUT_STATUS, OUT_MESSAGE;

        CALL LOG_ERROR( 'ADD_NEW_USER', UTIL_GET_ERROR_MESSAGE( 'in-created-by-null' ));

    ELSE 
        SELECT U.ROLE_ID, U.CREATED_BY INTO logged_in_user_role_id, user_who_created_logged_in_user FROM USERS U WHERE U.ID = IN_CREATED_BY;
        SELECT R.ID INTO to_be_created_user_role_id FROM ROLES R WHERE R.ROLE = IN_ROLE;

        /**
            * If user has provided invalid role.
            */
        IF to_be_created_user_role_id = NULL THEN
            SELECT 'N', UTIL_GET_ERROR_MESSAGE( 'in-valid-role-provided' ) INTO OUT_STATUS, OUT_MESSAGE;
        ELSE

            /**
                * Lets' see if logged in user has more authority than the one we are trying to create.
                */
                IF to_be_created_user_role_id <= logged_in_user_role_id THEN
                    SELECT 'N', UTIL_GET_ERROR_MESSAGE( 'permission-denied' ) INTO OUT_STATUS, OUT_MESSAGE;
                    CALL CREATE_NOTIFICATION_FOR_USER( user_who_created_logged_in_user, CONCAT( GET_USER_IDENTIFICATION( IN_CREATED_BY), 'tried to create an account of higher authority.'));

                ELSE 

                    /**
                        * Lets' check if user name already present in the database.
                        */
                        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO matching_row_count_user_name FROM USERS U WHERE U.USER_NAME = IN_USER_NAME;
                        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO matching_row_count_user_e_mail FROM USERS U WHERE U.EMAIL = IN_EMAIL;

                        IF matching_row_count_user_name > 0 THEN
                            SELECT 'N', UTIL_GET_ERROR_MESSAGE('username-exists') INTO OUT_STATUS, OUT_MESSAGE;

                        ELSEIF matching_row_count_user_e_mail > 0 THEN
                            SELECT 'N', UTIL_GET_ERROR_MESSAGE( 'email-exists' ) INTO OUT_STATUS, OUT_MESSAGE;

                        ELSE
                            /**
                                * Now, we are good to insert.
                                */
                                START TRANSACTION;

                                /**
                                    * Inserting into credentials first.
                                    */
                                    INSERT INTO CREDENTIALS( PASSWORD, LOCKED ) VALUES ( IN_PASSWORD, 'N' );
                                    INSERT INTO USERS( F_NAME, L_NAME, USER_NAME, EMAIL, ROLE_ID, ACTIVE, DELETED, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, CREDENTIAL_ID, LAST_ACTOR_ID )
                                                    VALUES( IN_FIRST_NAME, IN_LAST_NAME, IN_USER_NAME, IN_EMAIL, to_be_created_user_role_id, 'Y', 'N', IN_CREATED_BY, NOW(), LAST_INSERT_ID(), IN_CREATED_BY );

                                    INSERT INTO HISTORY_USER_EVENTS( USER_ID, TEXT, TYPE ) VALUES( LAST_INSERT_ID(), 
                                            CONCAT( UTIL_GET_USER_IDENTIFICATION( LAST_INSERT_ID() ), '''s account was created by ', UTIL_GET_USER_IDENTIFICATION( IN_CREATED_BY ), '.'),
                                            UTIL_GET_EVENT_ID_FOR_ACCOUNT_ACTION( 'Created' ));

                                    INSERT INTO HISTORY_ADMIN_EVENTS( ADMIN_ID, TEXT, TYPE ) VALUES( IN_CREATED_BY,
                                            CONCAT( UTIL_GET_USER_IDENTIFICATION( IN_CREATED_BY ), ' created account of ', UTIL_GET_USER_IDENTIFICATION( LAST_INSERT_ID()), ' with role ', IN_ROLE, '.' ),
                                            UTIL_GET_EVENT_ID_FOR_USER_ADDITION( IN_ROLE ));

                                    SELECT 'Y', 'User created.' INTO OUT_STATUS, OUT_MESSAGE;
                                    COMMIT;
                        END IF;
                END IF;


        END IF;

    END IF;

END
```

As you can see, I have created a handler that executes in case of any SQL exception. The procedure should produce a lot of run time errors. However,

I am not able to retrieve any of the `RETURNED_SQL_STATE` or `MYSQL_ERROR_CODE` OR `MESSAGE_TEXT` ? They all get value `null`.

Is it because I am calling rollback initially ? And it somehow messes up all the relevant information ?

Comment: Please explain downvote.

Comment: Try: `GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQ ...`. See [14.6.7.3 GET DIAGNOSTICS Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/get-diagnostics.html).

Comment: GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS worked for me. Thanks! I've read through the documentation and noticed this line:
"The keyword STACKED means to retrieve information from the second diagnostics area, which is available only if the current context is a condition handler." Am I correct in saying that an exit handler is a condition handler? This may be a stupid question. I've just begun moving from SQL Server to MySQL so I'm asking a lot of stupid questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of rollback **code block** with ability to log the error to some other table without loosing the exception details in MySQL and throwing the error again after logging it. You should get diagnostics BEFORE the ROLLBACK.

```
# CREATE PROCEDURE AND OTHER DECLARE STATEMENTS HERE
# ....

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;

    ROLLBACK;

    SET @full_error = CONCAT('ERR:', @errno, '(', @sqlstate, '):', @text);

    CALL sp_logaction(@full_error); # Some logging procedure

    RESIGNAL;
END;
# PROCEDURE BODY WITH START TRANSACTION & COMMIT HERE
# .....
```

Answer (score -2):

Seems you miss to add DELIMITER in your script.

DELIMITER |

you code .. .. ..

DELIMITER;

Thanks

Comment: Down vote. This is not the issue. The script provided seems to be from MySQL workbench "Alter Stored Procedure..." option. It leaves out delimiters.